# Moving some files from one hdd to other on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, filesystems

I've bought a new hdd for my machine and installed ubuntu on it. I wanted to copy some of my files to the new hdd from the old one which was previously my primary hdd so I used `fdisk -l` to get the partition list, yet it displayed only GPT, so I've tried to mount it but the only thing that was there was `<mount folder>/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`. I couldn't find anything resembling the `/` folder.
So how can i transfer some of my files from my old hdd to the new one?
**UPD:** Problem was resolved by reading [this](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/Mounting_a_Linux_LVM_volume.html) article, and using `vgchange -a y [VGName]` if LV status was 'NOT available'

Comment: Your question is very confusing, `fdisk` cannot show GPT disks so that isn't a surprise.  But what is confusing is you then say "so I've tried to mount it", mount which, to where, and how? And then on what you tried to mount was only the `/EFI/*`?  What do you mean you can't find anything resembling the `/` folder, what does it mean to resemble a `/` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your old disk device name? use parted for gpt disks to find out its partition.

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb print
```

then mount the appropriate partition. You may have mounted the wrong object based on erroneous display from fdisk, I think. So you need to make sure that the correct partition is mounted in the first place.

Also, what is your mount command, and what does the following command show?

```
sudo mount
```

Comment: Why is this an answer?  These look like things that all belong in comments to me.

Comment: Thanks. I added some clarification. I think it answers the question why files were not found -> incorrect partition or rather device was mounted because fdisk cannot correctly identify the partitions of a gpt disk.

Comment: `sudo mount` gives this [link](http://pastebin.com/745mAq5c)
`sudo parted /dev/sdb print` returns [link](http://pastebin.com/TCg1U20r)
As I suppose the last partition in what parted printed me is the one I need.

Comment: yes, the last one, but that is an lvm partition, so you need to use lvm commands such as lvdisplay to find logical volumes to mount,not partitions.

Answer (score 0):

**Use gdisk to list partitions for GPT disks.**

```
gdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

**Another useful command to determine partitions (provided they are labelled)**

```
blkid
```

**Use GParted to view all drive partitions**

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
sudo gparted
```

For GPT+UEFI bootable disks, partition 1 is a *FAT32 "ESP" partition* which is what you were seeing. The root filesystem for your old drive is probably on `/dev/sdb2`